# Bootstrap modal loaded.bs.modal is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I trigger a modal to load, and then I want to work on the content with coffee/javascript
however the loaded event isnt working. I have the latest bootstrap version installed 3.2.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="/messages/new" data-target="#modal" data-remote="true">
```

I have the following cofeescript that works (but fires upon showing which might not always work if the loading of the modal content is delayed)

```
$("#modal").on "shown.bs.modal", (e) ->
    $(".typeahead-patient-search-box").typeahead 
        name: 'patients'
        remote:
            url: '../patients.json?query=%QUERY',
            filter: (respData) ->
                $(respData).each ->
                    this.value = this.full_name 
                    this.tokens =  $(this.full_name).text().split(/\s+/)
        footer: "<a href='/patients/new'>Add New<a/>"
```

but changing it to this (note that i changed the event to loaded)

```
$("#modal").on "loaded.bs.modal", (e) ->
    $(".typeahead-patient-search-box").typeahead 
        name: 'patients'
        remote:
            url: '../patients.json?query=%QUERY',
            filter: (respData) ->
                $(respData).each ->
                    this.value = this.full_name 
                    this.tokens =  $(this.full_name).text().split(/\s+/)
        footer: "<a href='/patients/new'>Add New<a/>"
```

I have isolated the appropriate bootstrap code...

```
if (this.options.remote) {
      this.$element
        .find('.modal-content')
        .load(this.options.remote, $.proxy(function () {
          this.$element.trigger('loaded.bs.modal')
        }, this))
    }
  }
```

with breakpoints i can confirm that .find('.modal-content') runs but the breakpoint at  this.$element.trigger('loaded.bs.modal') is never triggered and i cant work out why?!?

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: The `remote` option of modals is being deprecated in v3.2.1 anyway, so I'd recommend just not using it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I think I might actually be using 3.2.1   . Is there an alternative that can be used? Remote seems quite useful is there a reason it is being removed?

Comment: Do the loading and/or templating yourself instead. Some more info: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14034